# Statically linking libs in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2005, static-linking

When you choose `/MTd` static linking in Visual Studio, would it try to link to each lib statically or there are some exceptions to system libs?

Answer (score 0):

Description: /MTd: Defines _DEBUG and _MT. This option also causes the compiler to place the library name LIBCMTD.lib into the .obj file so that the linker will use LIBCMTD.lib to resolve external symbols.

From what I can see there is no static linking. If you want to do static linking you need to use [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0). And even then you should not attempt to merge in the required .Net Framework references as they often reference others which you may miss. It may not even be possible as they use GAC for referencing.

Answer (score 0):

The /MT and /MD flags only define how the C/C++ runtime library is linked in. It has no effect on other libraries, system or user defined.

The system libraries, such as kernel32.lib, user32.lib, etc) are import libraries - there is no static library to link with.